# Understanding which variables impact your variable of interest the most (correlation, linear regression) and correctly interpreting results

Tags: feature-selection, linear-regression, correlation, feature-importances

How do you ascertain which variables lead to the greatest increase in another variable of interest?

Let's say you have a correlation matrix. You look at the row of the variable you are particularly curious about, `retention`, and see that `income` is the most correlated with it out of all the variables in the matrix.

I would then expect when I look at the highest income cities in my dataset to see them having highest `retention` but am not finding that to be the case. Why is that?

I am having a similar issue with weighted coefficients in a linear regression as well.

Trying to isolate for which variables to look into to see which impact `retention` most and am not understanding why highest income areas don't have most `retention` (if they are most correlated/ have highest weighted coefficient). I'm not trying to do any predictive models.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have data like in this R code:

```
library(ISLR)
df = ISLR::Auto
df = df[,1:4]

summary(df)
round(cor(df), 2)
```

If you look at the correlation...

```
               mpg cylinders displacement horsepower
mpg           1.00     -0.78        -0.81      -0.78
cylinders    -0.78      1.00         0.95       0.84
displacement -0.81      0.95         1.00       0.90
horsepower   -0.78      0.84         0.90       1.00
```

... it hints that `displacement` has "highest" impact on `mpg`. You may also expect that `mpg` and `displacement` are negatively related. However, keep in mind that [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) measures linear effects and does not give a good idea of "how strong" variables are related but rather "how well" a linear fit can possibly "explain" the relation.

So in oder to see which variable leads to "greatest increase" you could employ a linear regression (seems OK in this case according to the correlation).

```
reg1 = lm(mpg~cylinders+displacement+horsepower,data=df)
summary(reg1)

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  39.305268   1.324633  29.673  < 2e-16 ***
cylinders    -0.719431   0.434180  -1.657 0.098331 .  
displacement -0.029120   0.008623  -3.377 0.000807 ***
horsepower   -0.059935   0.013498  -4.440 1.17e-05 ***
```

Based on the regression coefficients you would suspect that `cylinders` has the "greatest" impact. However, you need to keep some things in mind.

- The effect of `cylinders` is conditional on the remaining $x$-variables (so "controlled for" the rest of the $x$)
- The effect of `cylinders` is measured in terms of "an increase in one cylinder would decrease `mpg` by -0.719, all other things equal (!!) on average (!!)"
- The effect of `cylinders` is statistically not different from zero. So the effect could be zero or possibly even negative (see the p-value).
- When you summarize the data, you will find that they have a different scale. So `cylinders` is measured in a different "unit" than `displacement` etc.

You need to bring all data *on the same scale* (to have `mean = 0` and `standard deviation = 1`) in order to compare the coefficients in terms of "size".

```
df_scaled = data.frame(scale(df))
reg2 = lm(mpg~cylinders+displacement+horsepower,data=df_scaled)
summary(reg2)

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   2.497e-16  2.927e-02   0.000 1.000000    
cylinders    -1.572e-01  9.489e-02  -1.657 0.098331 .  
displacement -3.904e-01  1.156e-01  -3.377 0.000807 ***
horsepower   -2.956e-01  6.657e-02  -4.440 1.17e-05 ***
```

With the new scaled data, you come to a different conclusion. Namely that `displacement` has "strong" impact. This (sometimes called [beta coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardized_coefficient)) is what may come next to what "greatest impact" in the context of regression analysis can mean.

Here the definition is: "a one standard deviation increase in $x$ will lead to a change queal to $\beta$ in $y$. So all $x$ are comparable now (because of scaling to mean = 0, standard deviation = 1).